# I want to get information from some tag in HTML in C Objective

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode

I am building an application for the iPhone, I get a string from the user.  I append the string to the end of some URL and it takes me to the site that I want.

Now I want to take some information from the site, for example I want to take all the string behind two tags `<title> HTML Test Page </title>`.  I need to parse this.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any valid JavaScript script code passed to the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: method of the UIWebView instance and parse what it returns.

Hope, this helps.

UPDATE:
a simple example will be the following; when your UIWebView has finished loading an URL, you can do the following

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
  NSString *output = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.title"];
  NSLog(@"Loaded page HTML title: %@", output);
}
```

as the parameter to the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: method you can pass a JavaScript code you need for finding your tag using DOM API

Comment: sorry but this func: "webViewDidFinishLoad" not recognize it's give me error, I try to edit your function to my use but I can't because she's not recognize

Comment: what do you mean, it's not recognized? it's UIWebViewDelegate method... just try to search the docs http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006951-CH3-SW4

Comment: sorry now is recognize and everything ok but I still not understand so good what I put instead of @"document.title" and this @"Loaded page HTML title: %@"    ??

Comment: document.title - is a JS code, that should return you a value of the <title/> tag in the loaded HTML document; @"Loaded page HTML title: %@" is a standard syntax for declaration of the format string, where instead of the %@ value of output variable will be printed out

Comment: ahh I see and If I want another TAG like <tr>

Comment: if you're not familiar with JS, give it a shot with a short tutorial or google query like this http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Development/GetelementbynamegetElementsByName.htm

Comment: I don't need to learn about JS I only want to know how to take some text from:
<tr><td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px;"> SOMETHING HERE</td></tr>

Comment: to do that, you need to find a proper JS statement - I believe it will be useful to get some JS basics for you, not the whole thing